# Como manejar los campos auditoria con ADO.NET en c#

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, ado.net

Tengo creado una APiRestful en netcore 3.0, y como podria setear los campos auditoria como por ejemplo:
**CreatedByUser, CreatedDate, ModifiedByUser, ModifiedDate** , he visto varios ejemplos con EntityFramework , pero todo mi acceso a datos lo hago con ADO.net.

Comment: Tu pregunta es como medio ambigua, cual es el problema particular que tenes?

Comment: Necesito saber que usuario agrego o actualizo dicho modelo en la bd sql, por medio de ado.net, o de que manera podria manejar mis auditorias.

Comment: Pero no tiene nada que ver con ado.net tu pregunta.. es mas generica, es como manejar auditorias, lo cual lo podes hacer desde tu sistema o desde la base de datos con triggers.. asi como esta, seria basada en opiniones...